# PrettyPhoto Last Image in Gallery Loading First

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, prettyphoto, portfolio

http://2012.delineamultimedia.com/#home_portfolio

If you click on the Icon that jumps when you hover over BRIAN GUEHRING's gallery. You will activate the prettyPhoto pop-up gallery. For some reason it starts with the last image in the gallery. Is there a way to fix this so it starts with the first image in the gallery?

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

This is the script I'm using to start prettyPhoto, I'm scared another script might be screwing this up somehow.

Thank you in advance for your time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I found that if I put a <div style="display:none;"> </div> around all of the images but the first one it actually fixes my problem and starts with image 1/4 not 4/4. This solution seems a bit hacky but it will work. If anyone knows a less hacky way to do this I'm all ears!

Comment: I just also found out that my span tags around the image links in prettyPhoto might have been the reason behind the bug. If someone wants to answer my question please do so since I do not have these privileges yet in stackoverflow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

yes the   around all the images but the first one forces the first image to be 1/x, and subsequent images in the gallery with the div tags appear in the order listed in the code... if there is a better solution I would be happy to hear it ... here is my sample code:

```
    <div class="mask">  
    <a class="icon-image"
    href="../../images/Murals/Residential/GreekBath/GREEK_BATH_514X685.png"
    rel="GreekBath[gallery]"
    title="Flower Vase Detail">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </a>
    <div style="display:none;">
    <a class="icon-image"
    href="../../images/Murals/Residential/GreekBath/FLOWER_VASE.png"
    rel="GreekBath[gallery]"
    title="Toilette">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div style="display:none;">
    <a class="icon-image"       
    href="../../images/Murals/Residential/GreekBath/TOILETTE.png"
    rel="GreekBath[gallery]"
    title="Greek Bathroom">
    <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
    </div>
```